# Error in string do while

Tags: c

```
char str[6];

do
{
    printf("Enter the string you wanna check:");
    scanf("%s", str);

}
while(str != "exit");
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: Define "not work"

Comment: When user enters  "Exit", the loop does not break.

Comment: You are not comparing strings, but pointers to `char`. As already suggested, use `strcmp()`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str` will *never* equal `"exit"`, because you're comparing the addresses of two different sections of memory. You probably want to compare the *contents* of the strings, for which there is a function `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 4):

`"exit"` is a `char[5]` generated by the compiler at some address in the data segment.  This address is definitely different from the address of `str`, as two different objects cannot occupy the same location in memory.

The `!=` operator between expressions of type `char[]` compares two pointers.  These two pointers are the address of `"exit"` and the address of `str`, which, as I have already explained, will *never* be equal.

So, the expression `str != "exit"` will *never* evaluate to `true`.  Which brings us to another point: your compiler should have issued a warning about this condition being always false.  Which means that you are trying to program without `-Wall`.  Don't do this, you are never going to get very far.  Always use the highest warning level, and when you see warnings, ***always fix them***.

To correct the problem, do as [user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3121023/user3121023) suggested [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468725/error-in-string-do-while#comment77898358_45468725), and use `strcmp()` to compare strings.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: it *does not work* because you must use `strcmp(str, "exit")` to compare the strings and loop for as long as the return value of `strcmp()` is not 0.

The long answer is: there are more problems in this little code fragment:

- The array into which you read a word is very short and you do not limit the number of characters `scanf()` is likely to store there.  Any user input longer than 5 non space characters will cause undefined behavior.
- You do not check the return value of `scanf()`.  A premature end of file, such as redirecting input from an empty file, will cause an infinite loop.

Here is how the code can be written in a safer way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[80];

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter the string you wanna check:");
        if (scanf("%79s", str) != 1 || strcmp(str, "exit") == 0)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, use `strcmp` from the `<string.h>` header file.

```
char str[6];

do {
    printf("Enter the string you wanna check:");
    scanf("%s", str);
} while(!strcmp(str, "exit"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char str[6];

    do
    {
        printf("Enter the string you wanna check:");
        scanf("%s", str);

    }
    while(strcmp(str, "exit") != 0);

    return 0;
}
```